# Optimizing the list traversal with stream

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List<BatchDTO>` with the following class

```
public class BatchDTO {

    private String batchNumber;
    private Double quantity;
.
.
//Getters and setters
}
```

What I have to do is to sum up the total if the batchNumber is duplicate. I have used a LinkedHashMap to implement this, and did the iterations. But what I would like to have is a more optimized way. Can I use stream to do this in an optimized way.

```
private static List<BatchDTO > getBatchDTO (Map<String, BatchDTO > batchmap) {
    return batchmap.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private static Map<String, BatchDTO > getBatchMap(List<BatchDTO > batchList, Map<String, BatchDTO > batchMap) {
        for (BatchDTO  batchDTO  : batchList) {
            batchMap = getBatchMap(batchMap, batchDTO );
        }
    return batchMap;
}

private static Map<String, BatchDTO > getBatchMap(Map<String, BatchDTO > batchMap, BatchDTO  batchObject) {
    String batchCode = batchObject.getBatchNumber();
        if(!batchMap.containsKey(batchCode)) {
            batchMap.put(batchCode, batchObject);
        } else {
            batchObject.setQuantity(getTotalQuantity(batchMap,batchObject));
            batchMap.put(batchCode, batchObject);
        }
    return batchMap;
}

private static Double getTotalQuantity(Map<String, BatchDTO > batchmap, BatchDTO  batchObject) {
    return batchmap.get(batchObject.getBatchNumber()).getQuantity() + batchObject.getQuantity();
}
```

Comment: you can `stream`, `collect`, group by `batchNumber` and then reduce the values with `summming`/`counting` as required.

Comment: Optimized in what way? Runtime, memory, code readability, something else? How do you expect us to suggest something _more_ optimized if we don't know the baseline you're comparing the suggestions with (i.e. what you did so far)?

Comment: It's unclear what computation you want to perform.  What exactly does "sum up the total if the batchNumber is duplicate" mean?  I can think of at least three plausible, completely different interpretations right off the top of my head.

Comment: If a batch number appears three times, should it be counted once (a number that appears more than once), twice (two duplicates) or three times (all three appear more than once)?

Comment: Sorry to be vague I will share my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using stream api the way [@Naman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56807934/optimizing-the-list-traversal-with-stream#comment100169952_56807934) suggested in comments. And assuming `BatchDTO` has all args constructor you could return back from `Map` to `List<BatchDTO>`

```
List<BatchDTO> collect = list.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(BatchDTO::getBatchNumber, summingDouble(BatchDTO::getQuantity)))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> new BatchDTO(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

JavaDoc: [groupingBy()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-),
[summingDouble()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-)

Answer (score 2):

Probably a little unreadable with comments in the code, but this is all I have time for.

```
// Result will be a Map where the keys are the unique 'batchNumber's, and the
// values are the sum of the 'quantities' for those with that 'batchNumber'.
public Map<String, Double> countBatchQuantities(final List<BatchDTO> batches) {
    // Stream over all the batches...
    return batches.stream()

    // Group them by 'batch number' (gives a Map<String, List<BatchDTO>>)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(BatchDTO::getBatchNumber))

    // Stream over all the entries in that Map (gives Stream<Map.Entry<String, List<BatchDTO>>>)
            .entrySet().stream()

    // Build a map from the Stream of entries
    // Keys stay the same
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, 

    // Values are now the result of streaming the List<BatchDTO> and summing 'getQuantity'
                    entry -> entry.getValue().stream().mapToDouble(BatchDTO::getQuantity).sum()));
}
```

Note: I make no promises that this *is* more optimised than your existing approach...  But it does the job with Streams.
Note: This will throw an exception if the `quantity` is `null` for any of your `BatchDTO`s...